# Replacing RDLC usage in desktop and web apps

Tags: .net, azure, reporting-services, asp.net-core, azure-web-app-service

I'm in the process of rebuilding from the ground up a stock control and point of sale system I wrote for a small chain of shops. They have a web-based back end that they input all their data in and some Windows-based touch-screen PCs that they use for point of sale, talking back to the website via API calls. The web side of the deal is Bootstrap front end, ASP.Net webforms backend and the Windows side is Windows Forms. 
Both back and front-end have a requirement for PDF output, in the back-end for reporting; for the production of a receipt to hand to the customer at point of sale and for end of day reports and such, general paper stuff that comes out of a cash register. This used to be easy enough, I have RDLC files nicely designed, I fed them DataTable objects and called the Render method, out came my PDFs.

In an attempt to modernise myself, I'm rewriting the web backend in ASP.Net Core and I'm mulling between WPF and UWP for the point-of-sale till software. I note that WPF kinda supports the ReportViewer control via WindowsFormsHosts but that feels like a hack. From my reading there's no support for RDLC in Core and I can't even move it onto the SQL server as I believe Azure SQL doesn't support Reporting Services. 
I've spent literally a couple of weeks armed with Google to try and find out how Microsoft thinks I should do this now. There seem to be a few Javascript PDF options (no thanks) and maybe Stimulsoft Reporting. Or there's PowerBI which feels like a using a sledgehammer to crack a nut.

Can someone give me a hint here? I appreciate that I might be seen as asking for an opinion which is usually frowned upon, but consider this as asking for directions instead! Back in the day I used to do this sort of thing in VB4 with Crystal Reports. Someone get me back there :)

Thanks in advance...

Comment: What did you end up going with?  Facing a similar quandry myself...

Comment: There never was a really good answer to this. I did not and have not found a simple visual design tool to replace RDLC at all.
In the 3 years that have passed, I've done good things with MigraDoc but it's not being developed now. I reinvented myself as a JAM stack person and I've done projects with jsPDF, React-PDF and a few other Javascript libraries. I've produced PDF output with HTML conversion such as WKHTML2PDF, having first produced the HTML with Handlebars templating. It's fine, it all works but it's just not as good as drawing it and being able to see what you're doing.